# Error CS1926: Error opening Win32 manifest file

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, manifest

I wanted to add new empty class file.

Instead, I accidentally added new manifest file.

Then removed it and I get error:

### Error message:

> \CSC: Error CS1926: Error opening Win32 manifest file -- Could not find file MenuPage.manifest'. (CS1926) 
>   How can I change win32manifest compiler option?

Answer (score 19):

I just faced the same issue, creating by error a .manifest file inside my project, the solution I found was quite simple:

0) Close your project/solution

1) Locate the physical path for your project (C:/something)

2) Open with a text editor the .csproject file for your project

3) Here you can search for the manifest file name the compiler is asking for, you will find something like :

```
<ApplicationManifest>MenuPage.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
```

4) Delete that line

5) Open your project again

6) Compile

7) Drink a Beer

Comment: Lay off the beer...it's bad for you, now!